# Get altitude by longitude and latitude in Android

Tags: android, geolocation, gis, android-mapview

Is there a quick and efficient way to get altitude (elevation) by longitude and latitude on the Android platform?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

My approach is to use [USGS Elevation Query Web Service](http://gisdata.usgs.gov/xmlwebservices2/elevation_service.asmx):

```
private double getAltitude(Double longitude, Double latitude) {
    double result = Double.NaN;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    String url = "http://gisdata.usgs.gov/"
            + "xmlwebservices2/elevation_service.asmx/"
            + "getElevation?X_Value=" + String.valueOf(longitude)
            + "&Y_Value=" + String.valueOf(latitude)
            + "&Elevation_Units=METERS&Source_Layer=-1&Elevation_Only=true";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            int r = -1;
            StringBuffer respStr = new StringBuffer();
            while ((r = instream.read()) != -1)
                respStr.append((char) r);
            String tagOpen = "<double>";
            String tagClose = "</double>";
            if (respStr.indexOf(tagOpen) != -1) {
                int start = respStr.indexOf(tagOpen) + tagOpen.length();
                int end = respStr.indexOf(tagClose);
                String value = respStr.substring(start, end);
                result = Double.parseDouble(value);
            }
            instream.close();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {} 
    catch (IOException e) {}
    return result;
}
```

And example of use (right in [HelloMapView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) class):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.zoomview);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mZoom = (ZoomControls) mapView.getZoomControls();
        linearLayout.addView(mZoom);
        mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == 1) {
                    final GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                            (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                    final StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            final double lon = p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
                            final double lat = p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
                            final double alt = getAltitude(lon, lat);
                            msg.append("Lon: ");
                            msg.append(lon);
                            msg.append(" Lat: ");
                            msg.append(lat);
                            msg.append(" Alt: ");
                            msg.append(alt);
                        }
                    }).run();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: As somewhat GIS interested I find this very interesting

Comment: To amplify on this: the reason you need to do something like that (use a service on the network) is twofold: one, the GPS isn't very good at altitude, vertical errors are around 150 ft at times, and two, any reasonably high-resolution world elevation model is enormous, much too big to install on the phone.

If you were doing this on your own server as part of a web app or GIS, you could instead download the elevation model (from NASA) and query it directly; faster, but uses a lot of storage.

Comment: To clarify, this actually grabs the elevation and NOT the altitude of a lat/long point.

Comment: To clarify even more: altitude is measured by a device, which could be flying on a plane, for example. Elevation refers to the ground and does not change. Of course, only elevation could be fetched from a database.

Comment: Unless you guys are a lot taller than me, or drive in cars with ridiculous suspensions, altitude and elevation are virtually the same thing *in this context*.

Comment: gisdata.usgs.gov webservice does not work anymore. It redirects to nationalmap.gov site. But I've found no rest service doing the same there.

Comment: ARLabs, I think this is the replacement webservice:
http://ned.usgs.gov/epqs/

eg. http://ned.usgs.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=-95&y=38&units=Feet&output=xml

Answer (score 24):

You can also use the Google Elevation API. The online documentation for it is located at:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/

Please note the following from the above API page:

> Usage Limits: Use of the Google
>   Geocoding API is subject to a query
>   limit of 2,500 geolocation requests
>   per day. (User of Google Maps API
>   Premier may perform up to 100,000
>   requests per day.) This limit is
>   enforced to prevent abuse and/or
>   repurposing of the Geocoding API, and
>   this limit may be changed in the
>   future without notice. Additionally,
>   we enforce a request rate limit to
>   prevent abuse of the service. If you
>   exceed the 24-hour limit or otherwise
>   abuse the service, the Geocoding API
>   may stop working for you temporarily.
>   If you continue to exceed this limit,
>   your access to the Geocoding API may
>   be blocked. Note: the Geocoding API
>   may only be used in conjunction with a
>   Google map; geocoding results without
>   displaying them on a map is
>   prohibited. For complete details on
>   allowed usage, consult the Maps API
>   Terms of Service License Restrictions.

Altering [Max Gontar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67407/max-gontar) code above for the Google API gives the following, with the returned elevation given in feet:

```
private double getElevationFromGoogleMaps(double longitude, double latitude) {
        double result = Double.NaN;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/"
                + "xml?locations=" + String.valueOf(latitude)
                + "," + String.valueOf(longitude)
                + "&sensor=true";
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                int r = -1;
                StringBuffer respStr = new StringBuffer();
                while ((r = instream.read()) != -1)
                    respStr.append((char) r);
                String tagOpen = "<elevation>";
                String tagClose = "</elevation>";
                if (respStr.indexOf(tagOpen) != -1) {
                    int start = respStr.indexOf(tagOpen) + tagOpen.length();
                    int end = respStr.indexOf(tagClose);
                    String value = respStr.substring(start, end);
                    result = (double)(Double.parseDouble(value)*3.2808399); // convert from meters to feet
                }
                instream.close();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {} 
        catch (IOException e) {}

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's important to first differentiate altitude from elevation.

Altitude is the distance from a point down to the local surface; whether that be land or water. This measurement is mainly used for aviation.

Altitude can be obtained by using the [Location.getAltitude()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAltitude()) function.

Elevation is the distance from the local surface to the sea level; much more often used, and often mistakenly referred to as altitude.

With that said, for the US, USGS has provided a [newer HTTP POST and GET queries](http://ned.usgs.gov/epqs/) that can return XML or JSON values for elevation in either feet or meters. For worldwide elevation, you could use the [Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start).

Answer (score 3):

If u are using android device which has GPS Recever then there is a method **getAltitude()** by using that u can get the altitude by elevation.

Comment: Which object type is that method assigned to. You can't just give people half the cake.

Comment: Location object, when using Play Services's fused location API

Comment: You can use it in onLocationChanged(Location location){location.getAltitude()} but it always returns 0.0

Answer (score 2):

Try this one that I`v built: https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/Gaploid/Elevation

here is example for Java:

```
import com.algorithmia.*;
import com.algorithmia.algo.*;

String input = "{\"lat\": \"50.2111\", \"lon\": \"18.1233\"}";
AlgorithmiaClient client = Algorithmia.client("YOUR_API_KEY");
Algorithm algo = client.algo("algo://Gaploid/Elevation/0.3.0");
AlgoResponse result = algo.pipeJson(input);
System.out.println(result.asJson());
```

Answer (score 0):

Google maps have the altitude, what you need is this code

```
altitude="";
var init = function() {
        var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;
        map.on('mousemove', function(event) {
            getLocationElevation(event.latlng, elevator);
            document.getElementsByClassName("altitudeClass")[0].innerHTML = "Altitude: "+ getAltitude();
            //console.debug(getAltitude());
        });
}

var getLocationElevation = function (location, elevator){
  // Initiate the location request
  elevator.getElevationForLocations({
    'locations': [location]
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
      // Retrieve the first result
      if (results[0]) {
        // Open the infowindow indicating the elevation at the clicked position.
        setAltitude(parseFloat(results[0].elevation).toFixed(2));
      } else {
        setAltitude('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      setAltitude('Elevation service failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
function setAltitude(a){
    altitude = a;
}
function getAltitude(){
    return altitude;
}
```

Comment: Google maps have the altitude, what you need is put this code

Comment: Also, the service is no more free.

Answer (score -1):

The idea to use the Google Elevation API is good, but parsing XML using string functions is not. Also, HttpClient is deprecated now, as using insecure connections.

See here for a better solution:
https://github.com/M66B/BackPackTrackII/blob/master/app/src/main/java/eu/faircode/backpacktrack2/GoogleElevationApi.java