# Getting the altitude

Tags: android, android-mapview, mapactivity

In a class derived from the `MapActivity` class, I want to get the altitude of the point clicked by the user. So far, I know how to retrieve the latitude, the longitude but not the altitude.

Is it possible and how?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995998/android-get-altitude-by-longitude-and-latitude - check first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find yourself a Web service that can report the altitude for a given latitude and longitude. There is nothing built into Android for this.

Comment: @Zelig - Check out google elevation API - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/elevation/

Comment: Ok, I have found a web service which returns the altitude. But how can I use it in an Android application?