# Can be located which floor we are via smart phone GPS?

Tags: android, ios, gps, location

Is there a way that can decide which floor we are via smart phone?

For example, i m in a building. floor 5;

the native app in my smart phone can know i m on floor 5 and give me some advice about floor 5（navigation to floor 1）

Comment: This is impossible. You would need an elevation instrument, which I'm almost certain Android devices do not have.

Comment: You might get altitude, but I doubt you can get the floor. Unless you have altitude to floor mapping

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995998/android-get-altitude-by-longitude-and-latitude. Here is a pos the discusses a few ways to access elevation

Comment: use altitude difference perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some newer Android phones (e.g., Samsung Galaxy S3), embedded barometric pressure sensors can be used to derive an accurate indoor altitude estimate, which could be transformed into floors (assuming you know which elevation the floor is located at).

See this article on STMicroeletronics pressure sensor:

http://www.engadget.com/2012/09/06/stmicroelectronics-details-pressure-sensor-in-your-galaxy-s-iii/

This app shows altitude based on barometric pressure:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snakebite.mike.altimeter

Here's the Android API:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getAltitude(float,%20float)

Comment: thnx for all guys' comments here. it is kind of a hard-practicing task. but I got some ways to work around. 1. we can use a phone ping multiple WiFi Hotspots, we can calculate which floor if you know where these spots are. 2. use fm, this can be available nearly everywhere. but first we need to know the signal strength at every floor 3. use Bluetooth to connect a device that is preinstalled in the floor