# What is number of Query Google API per day for Unity

Tags: geolocation, unity-game-engine

I am developing an application in which I am using Compas and GPS for iPhone Platform and after that I will make this for Android also in Unity.

So I am sniffing Compas related question and I found an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5672274/836214) that there is a Limit for Querying Google Api. I am a bit scared because I want to query each second to update user location and compas information of device.

Does anyone know what is the maximum limit of Query? What is a better approach to do this task?

Comment: Are you talking about The Google Elevation API or the Maps API or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Google Elevation API, then yes, there is a limit. Basically, ALL Google API's have Usage Limits. From the Elevation API webpage:

> Usage Limits
>
> Use of the Google Elevation API is subject to a limit of 2,500
>   requests per day (Maps API for Business users may send up to 100,000
>   requests per day). In each given request you may query the elevation
>   of up to 512 locations, but you may not exceed 25,000 total locations
>   per day (1,000,000 for Maps API for Business users). This limit is
>   enforced to prevent abuse and/or repurposing of the Elevation API, and
>   this limit may be changed in the future without notice. Additionally,
>   we enforce a request rate limit to prevent abuse of the service. If
>   you exceed the 24-hour limit or otherwise abuse the service, the
>   Elevation API may stop working for you temporarily. If you continue to
>   exceed this limit, your access to the Elevation API may be blocked.

If you need more requests, you may have to use Maps API for Business.