# can we programatically find out current altitude using google maps

Tags: android, android-maps

I am new to android programming and I just started with my basics and I had an idea for developing an app and for that I want to locate myself with the floor number in a multi storey building. For that I want to know wether there is any altitude service by google maps in case if that doesn't work is there any alternative to locate my floor number.

Thanks in advance

Comment: maps don't have a sensor, you will need to use GPS for that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361870/android-how-to-get-accurate-altitude

Comment: is there any internet connection ? you want to acheive this using an internet connection ?

Comment: Yes by using internet..

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995999/957654) which is usin the Elevation_Service , which returns the elevation in feet or meters for a specific latitutde/longitude  .

and please give me feedback

Hope That Helps .