# Get altitude,longitude,latitude from Android (eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, altitude

how can i get longitude,altitude,latitude from the android machine ?
I have been tried to get from the gps but with no sucsses (I got 0 of all the variable).
I'm using Eclipse with ADT.
thanks :)

Comment: are you using emulator or real device ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Get Altitude By Longitude and Latitude?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995998/android-get-altitude-by-longitude-and-latitude)

Comment: I'm using real device

Comment: Are you outside and have you given the gps time to get a fix.  May be several minutes the first time.