# Get elevation (altitude at ground level) using USGS Elevation Query Service API

Tags: android, api, gps, elevation

I have spent the better part of a week trying to research how to connect to the USGS Elevation Query Service API via my android app with embarrassing results.  The best I have found is from 6-years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995998/get-altitude-by-longitude-and-latitude-in-android) using now deprecated code.  Spoiler - I couldn't get it to work.

Using GPS for elevation is simply too unreliable for my application needs, even after extensive moving averages and low/high pass filtration applied to the data.

Can anyone share their recommendations/code to retrieve elevation via the USGS Elevation Query Service.  I can of course provide Latitude and Longitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple google search on "USGS Elevation Query Service API" pointed to http://ned.usgs.gov/epqs/ (different address from the question you linked. And the API seems extremely straight forward.

Here is an example call to Las Vegas http://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=36.1251958&y=-115.3150863&output=json&units=Meters

The problem is that as per their website "If unable to find data at the requested point, this service returns -1000000" and I personally couldn't find any location that they have location (tried Las Vegas and San Francisco).

Alternatively, Google have an elevation API, that I can only assume it's pretty damn good considering Google Maps. Here you can see the docs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start and here is an example query https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034

For the actual call itself, suggest is to use OkHttp (http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or Retrofit (which uses OkHttp) to do threading for you), but a basic code is:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String getElevation(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

then it's just parse the Json string

Comment: Thanks, up until now I've avoided Google.  As I understand it, Google provides a very limited number of calls before charging a fee.  But perhaps it is the best option.

Comment: I've checked the price and it seems free up to 2500 requests a day, but to be honest, I tried calling the API without any API key and it worked fine, too

Comment: @Budius how did you made that? Can you please tell me

Comment: @Prasad are you asking how did I search on Google or how did I copy-paste a standard OkHttp implementation from their docs?

Comment: @Budius i'm asking about elevation api without using API KEY

Comment: @Prasad I just didn't add it to the request URL. There's one in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I just came across this page looking for something related and noticed that there is an error in the first response.  It says this:

> Here is an example call to Las Vegas
>   http://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=36.1251958&y=-115.3150863&output=json&units=Meters
>
> The problem is that as per their website "If unable to find data at
>   the requested point, this service returns -1000000" and I personally
>   couldn't find any location that they have location (tried Las Vegas
>   and San Francisco).

The example has X and Y reversed.  Switch it to

```
https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?y=36.1251958&x=-115.3150863&output=json&units=Meters
```

and it works fine.  Hope this helps some future searcher!

Comment: x is longitude and y is latitude, x axis running across the equator and y axis running along the poles ... this gets me all the time

Answer (score 1):

You use the one you cited by simply replacing the deprecated httpClient by the Google's recommended HttpUrlConnection. There are a lot of tutorials out there including [Google's own sample code explained here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Comment: Thanks, I did try to convert.  My kung foo was not strong enough.