# How to get point's elevation ? ( without internet )

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, elevation, android-elevation

How to get point's elevation ( without internet) ? I have coordinates of that point and need to calculate its elevation in offline mode. I am using GoogleMaps ( caching it and using it offline ).

Comment: Well, it seems that you cannot do it without the internet. The Google Maps API has a [Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro) that can help you with this. It provides a simple interface to query locations on the earth for elevation data. Additionally, you may request sampled elevation data along paths, allowing you to calculate elevation changes along routes. But this API require an internet, it uses https in requesting with the API. For more information, check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995998).

Comment: This application do the same.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilyabogdanovich.geotracker&hl=en