# Android - Google Maps API v2 - get altitude of location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-api-2, elevation

I am using Google Maps API v2 in my Android application, and I would like to know how could I get an elevation details of a specific route, e.g for a 10km route ahead. I'd like to update this graph on every location change.

I know I can get it like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995998/get-altitude-by-longitude-and-latitude-in-android). This however is not possible for me. I have the map area downloaded for an offline use. I just want the API to give me the elevation data from those, without connecting to the internet.

Comment: Did you even attempt to do any research? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAltitude()

Comment: I already have that. I a searching for the solution for few weeks now. 
I don't want to get the elevation of my position. I want to get the ground elevation of a different point. E.g. of the place the user clicks on the map.
I don't want to make request that needs internet. I want it offline using the offline area I have saved via the GoogleMaps app.

Comment: no google maps does not provide this information